# How much clearance do I need between floating ground and earth referenced ground?

Tags: safety

I have two circuits where one side is earth reference and another floating. The floating circuit is isolated by a transformer and talk to the earth reference circuit via opto-coupler.

During final phase of development, i noticed my floating ground shield got too close of the chassis ground with only less than 0.1mm of gap. I immediately tagged it as issue and as usual people will ask me how much gap I needed. (I don't really have an answer, I am only a mfg engineer). I go through some safety standard but I still don't have an clear answer.

Here is my question:

1. Do I need to have clearance between two grounds to avoid hazard or arc?
2. Since both points are concealed within a metal cover which are grounded, do I need to follow the clearance requirement as required by the safety standard?
3. if that is not required, then how much of gap do I need to prevent a arc over? Should I follow the safety standard clearance guideline or should i follow the 30kV/cm rules?

Comment: how much voltage do you want to withstand? Is it a safety / regulations issue, or just a physics issue? Does the equipment have to operate in high humidity and dust?

Comment: Speak to the designer - it's not your responsibility as manufacturing engineer to determine this.

Comment: Did [Jeroen3's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/503799/36731) answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to have clearance between two grounds to avoid hazard or arc?

Yes. Is suspect this is **functional isolation** required for the operation of the device, but not to protect users from shock.

> Since both points are concealed within a metal cover which are grounded, do I need to follow the clearance requirement as required by the safety standard?

You need to comply to the relevant standard. They will have requirements with a test scenario for the isolation barrier.

Eg: 50178:1997 (A.9.4.6.5)
- insulation resistance: 100 MΩ;
- dielectric strength: a.c. 1 kV or d.c. 1,5 kV (60 s duration);
- pulse withstand: 1,2/50 ms, 2 kV (peak value)

Even if the standards are not a requirement, use them as guideline.

---

If it is **safety isolation** then all of the above is invalid, the standards are mandatory and significant distances and strict requirements on parts apply. And have your device tested by a certified auditor.